# How to undo kubectl delete node

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I have a k8s cluster on Azure created with asc-engine.  It has 4 windows agent nodes.

Recently 2 of the nodes went into a not-ready state and remained there for over a day.  In an attempt to correct the situation I did a "kubectl delete node" command on both of the not-ready nodes, thinking that they would simply be restarted in the same way that a pod that is part of a deployment is restarted.

No such luck.  The nodes no longer appear in the "kubectl get nodes" list.  The virtual machines that are backing the nodes are still there and still running.  I tried restarting the VMs thinking that this might cause them to self register, but no luck.

How do I get the nodes back as part of the k8s cluster?  Otherwise, how do I recover from this situation?  Worse case I can simply throw away the entire cluster and recreate it, but I really would like to simply fix what I have.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the virtual machines and rerun your acs engine template, that *should* bring the nodes back (although, i didnt really test your exact scenario). Or you could simply create a new cluster, not that it takes a lot of time, since you just need to run your template.

There is no way of recovering from deletion of object in k8s. Pretty sure they are purged from etcd as soon as you delete them.

Comment: Yes, good idea.  Except how to do this?  I have the ARM template that acs-engine created.  The template seems to be only good for creating a new cluster in an empty resource group.  That is the command used is "az group deployment create".  There is no corresponding "az group deployment update".  It seems that deleting the cluster and recreating it completely is the only option.

Comment: `deployment create` creates deployment, not cluster. deployment does something. you just rerun the template. it should create the new node, it should add the node back

Comment: While indeed it takes little time to recreate the cluster, it is more than rerunning the ARM template.  To delete the cluster I have to remove the entire resource group and along with it the service principal ("best practice" according to tutorial is to put service principal in RG).  So new RG and new SP requires running acs-engine again, so new ARM template and attendant ripple effect through out.

Comment: you dont need to remove the resource group, you just need to rerun the template. service principal cannot be put into a resource group. its an Azure AD entity, not connected to Azure Resource Manager entities. Looks like you are mixing lot of stuff up.

Comment: Indeed.  So I deleted the 2 VMs and did another deployment.  It failed with a cryptic error "CanceledAndSupersededDueToAnotherOperation".  Here is what is interesting:  I deleted the 1st and 4th nodes in the cluster and the 1st node was recreated and I can see it now with kubectl get nodes.  So your approach is close to working.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: thats a really weird error. what if you rerun it again? template deployment is giving you that? can you dig out the real error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189324/discussion-between-aquirky-and-4c74356b41).